# What is the time complexity of Python's search operation "some_element in some_list"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example, I have a list l of n numbers, what is the time complexity for the search operation:

```
if 35 in l:
    # ......
```

Is it O(1) or O(n)?

Comment: First search result for "Python time complexity", see the first table: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity. Checking `x in s` is `O(n)`.

Answer (score 1):

In CPython, O(n). https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity see the third entry from the bottom in the "list" table.

Answer (score 1):

The `x in y` syntax works for many things, so it depends on the type of `y`.

For instance, if `y` is a `dict` or `set`, then the average case is O(1).
Where as if `y` is a list, then the time complexity is O(n).

As mentioned before, the table with complexities is here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity